Short story I read >50 years ago about giving political candidates' families illnesses to get sympathy votes
I think the story was in a magazine. All I remember is political candidates who were not doing well in polls would visit a shaman type person who would give the candidate's family member a real ailment so that voters would feel sorry for them and vote them into office.
